# Build automation using TFS with InstallShield 2011

Tags: tfs, installation, installshield, tfsbuild

We have a TFS build which outputs 2 exe's for 2 different solutions. How do I now integrate my build with InstallShield to use these exe's of both the solutions in my installer.

Any points to information would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks much in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

There is no "as is" integration for this in TFS/MsBuild.  You must open the msbuild script that TFS uses for each of your solutions and specify a target that will launch installshield.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the integrated into VisualStudio version of InstallShield 2011, the setup can be part of the solution. But you have to install the stand alone version of InstallShield on TFS build machine. This done, InstallShield projects are built automatically by TFS, too.